# installation Rcmdr can't load

Tags: r, syntax-error

```
> library(Rcmdr)
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: carData
Loading required package: sandwich
Loading required package: effects
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'lme4':
  method                          from
  cooks.distance.influence.merMod car 
  influence.merMod                car 
  dfbeta.influence.merMod         car 
  dfbetas.influence.merMod        car 
lattice theme set by effectsTheme()
See ?effectsTheme for details.
RcmdrMsg: [1] CATATAN: Versi R Commander 2.6-2: Thu Feb 06 11:52:32 2020

Versi Rcmdr 2.6-2


Attaching package: 'Rcmdr'

The following object is masked from 'package:base':

    errorCondition
```

Hello, i am a beginner in r and i have a problem.

my R is 3.6.2 version, i use win 10 and i can't load Rcmdr...
is there a way to fix it?

Thx

Comment: it hangs? because the message you have about masking is ok

Comment: Or are you having problems loading the graphical interface? Maybe check this ? https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html

Comment: It appears Rcmdr is loaded. errorCondition from pkg:base has been masked by another value from Rcmdr. `errorCondition` is a function that is used during debugging or to deliver informative messages inside otehr functions. That is a misleading message. If you had encountered an error you would have seen the word "Error"